# how to pass URL further in to response using fetch?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this fetch request a I am accepting it to

1. send me a statement !! if certain conditions are met
2. redirect me to anther page after certain time
   problem is those 2 don't seem to work together if I send json resp the link is pointing to the default one future more I cannot pass the URL further down the response.

```js
// Server side 
exports.redirect = async (req, res, next) => {
        //res.status(403)
        res.json({ Error: 'Plase try again' })
        res.redirect('/signup')
}

// Client side
fetch('/redirect', {
      credentials: "same-origin",
      mode: "same-origin",
      method: 'POST',
      //redirect: 'follow',
      headers: {
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${jwt}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(inputJSON)
      })
      .then(resp => {
        console.log(resp.url)
        return Promise.all([resp.json()])
      }
      ).then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        let jsonData = data[0]
        let div = document.querySelector(".form-group");
        div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<div id="response">${jsonData.Error}</div>`)
        //setTimeout(windows.location = data.url, 5000);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }).catch(err => {
        if (err === "server") return
        console.log(err)
      })

  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the general situation of when you want to pass something from an upper `.then` to a lower one, you'd be almost there, you just need to add the `resp.url` to the `Promise.all` array you already have:

```
.then(resp => {
    return Promise.all([resp.json(), resp.url])
}
).then(([data, url]) => {
    const div = document.querySelector(".form-group");
    div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<div id="response">${data.Error}</div>`);
    setTimeout(() => window.location = url, 5000);
})
```

But it doesn't make much sense to have a response that both has `.json()` *and* a redirect - pick one or the other. I'd recommend only a `.json`:

```
exports.redirect = async (req, res, next) => {
        res.json({ Error: 'Plase try again', url: '/signup' });
}
```

```
.then(res => res.json())
.then(result => {
  div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<div id="response">${result.Error}</div>`);
  setTimeout(() => window.location = result.url, 5000);
})
```

Also make sure to pass a callback to `setTimeout`, and to use `window.location`, not `windows.location`.

Your final `.catch(err => {` block is superfluous too, it'll never be entered into and doesn't really make any sense anyway - feel free to completely remove it.

Comment: the problem now is it is showing the defult link not the new link ! res.redirect('/signup')